# Apache server doesn't work on external IP (ports are forwarded)

Tags: apache, port, external

Here is my situation, step by step:

- Apache 2.2 on Windows 7
- Restarted the apache server plenty of times up to my latest changes being described here
- Changed apache's port from 80 to 8080. There is only one "Listen" for 8080 and not for other ports like 80
- Type localhost on browser and doesnt work as expected
- type localhost:8080 and everything works perfectly
- go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/ and http://www.canyouseeme.org/ while apache is running, they report port 8080 is open
- type my external IP (the same one reported by yougetsignal.com above) followed by :8080 and get "this webpage is not available"
- Windows firewall is completely turned off during these tests
- People that access my external IP actually get my router asking for user and pass authentication (I have no auth requests on htaccess or config)

  What on earth could be causing the external ip not to work properly?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that from outside your network your ip external address directs traffic to your router since it is the first thing connected to your modem. This is why some of your users saw your router page. You will need to setup port forwarding in your router to forward requests on port 8080 from your router directly to your computer where you are hosting the site. Note: There are some potential security risks with opening ports which can search online.

Here is an example instructional video, or you can search for other port forwarding instructions online. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kp-R-eHiQco

From there you will also need to open the Windows Firewall ports for port 8080 (or turn it off) as you have done. That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Found two different problems:

1. My router always has port 8080 open, whether I forward or not. It could be using it for something internal which was conflicting with apache. So my advice to everyone out there, make sure you pick a CLOSED port to use on apache to begin with
2. I changed to port 4000, and tested it. Didnt work for a minute, messed with settings, went back to original 4000 setting and bam. Works. Turned server off, turned back on, still working and port is open. As I suspected, turned server off, left PC on, went to take a shower, came back 10 min later, turned server back on and not working anymore and websites list port 4000 as closed.

   So it appears that my router is inconsistent, sometimes he can open the port and sometimes cant for some reason.